# Interpolation from irregular grid to regular grid

Tags: numpy, scipy, time-series

I have some 1D data (time series data) that is sampled irregularly; i.e., non-constant sample rate. I would like transform these data into a regularly sampled (uniform sample rate) time series. I have used linear interpolation in an attempt to accomplish this; however, this is not very effective when there is a large variation in the time between samples. This is no surprise. I have also attempted some *ad hoc* methods that again are not very effective.

I have looked at several papers on the use of **matching pursuit** for interpolation over irregular grids; but, how this approach could be used to obtain samples over a regular grid is not clear to me (at least not yet).

I would appreciate any suggestions on algorithms for interpolation from irregular grids to regular grids (1D data).

Comment: What exactly have you found "not very effective" in using linear interpolation?

Comment: Jaime, linear interpolation is not effective when there are large gaps. It should be clear that linear simulation over a large gap will place all the estimated (interpolated) values on a straight line --- this almost never happens in reality with measured data. This can also be easily shown via simulation by removing samples of random length. This is what I meant by "not very effective". If you would like I can supply some references on this.

Comment: Note, I have used a state-space-model and applied a continuous-time Kalman filter followed by an RTS smoother that can be used to estimate the smoothed TS. However, this does not really solve my problem. I am not trying to smooth the data; but, rather find an estimate of the measured signal over a regular grid.

Comment: The thing is that you have missing data, so you need to be more precise about what properties would you like your interpolated (a.k.a. as "made up") values to have. Would you rather have them sit on a parabola than a line? Use a piecewise quadratic interpolator. On a sinusoidal wave? Try a Fourier approach. Randomly chosen? There really is no right answer unless you know the behavior of your real data very well, or have a precise request for the interpolator, e.g. continuous first two derivatives.

Comment: You have misinterpreted my request -- **I do not have missing data**. There are gaps in the data and one way to view this (as often used in text books on signal processing) is continuous data in which some random samples are taken. This is fact the approach often used for filtering-smoothing of irregularly sampled data. The data is there being recorded continuously but the samples are taken at random. It may be of interest for you to know that it can be shown that random sampling has some advantages; e.g. a higher Nyquist frequency.

Comment: The "gaps" are what Jaime means by "missing data". If you want to interpolate "better" than linear interpolation, you need to specify what is "better" for your specific application --- there is no universal answer here, it all depends on prior knowledge on what the data should be like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fit the data points exactly, run
[scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html)
with `s=0`
(and ask further if that's not clear).